# Can't find file or directory on disk that do exists

Tags: go

I am currently investigating go to learn more about it, but I've found my way into a wall that I can't break through. What I am trying to do is take user input for a directory or file, etc: /Users/me/Documents/test.sql and copy it to another directory, etc: /usr/local/share/myprogram

The problems is that os.Lstat does not find it with anything I try...

I know that test.sql exists, if I use open /Users/me/Documents/test.sql in the terminal, that Go doesn't say it can't find I manage to open it, so it is there.

Why is this happening? Is this something with go and the path is set to only find files in the working directory? And how do I overcome this?

```golang
os.Lstat("/Users/me/Documents/test.sql")
```

I've also tried using filepath

```golang
toPath, _ := filepath.Abs("/Users/me/Documents/test.sql")
os.Lstat(toPath)
```

I expect this file to be found, but it isn't

Comment: What is the _exact_ error you're seeing? What happens when you copy+paste the string from the `Lstat` arguments and `ls -l` it from the cli?

Comment: You say you are reading user input, but your code doesn't reflect that. Is it really failing when you hardcode the filename?

Answer (score 0):

The [docs](https://golang.org/src/os/stat.go?s=642:683#L10) says:

> **Lstat** returns a FileInfo describing the named file. If the file is a symbolic link, the returned FileInfo describes the symbolic link. Lstat makes no attempt to follow the link. If there is an error, it will be of type *PathError.

**Here's an example you could try:**

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    desc, err := os.Lstat("/Users/me/Documents/test.sql")
    if err != nil {
        // prints the error and stop
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    // prints the filename
    fmt.Println(desc.Name())
}
```